# How to serialize Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> to generate Metrics Json Object

Tags: java, spring, serialization, apache-kafka, gson

I've tried to serialize my `Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>>` object using `Gson` but I'm getting JSON String response.And also I have the metrics value and name in that inner `Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>` Here is my code looks like:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/showRawKafkaMetrics", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getMetrics() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for (MessageListenerContainer container : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()){
            list.add(gson.toJson(container.metrics()));
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is `MetricName` and `Metric`? How is the returning `List<String>` related to the metrics map structure?

Comment: Kafka already has a built-in JSON serializer with Jackson. Why use Gson?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting JSON String response

Well, you are returning `List<String>`

If you want Spring to return JSON, then add a response mapping for `application/json` (which you did; `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`)

If you're expecting some response like

```
{
  "foo": {
    "metric": "bar" 
  }
}
```

Then you cannot return `List<?>` since that is an Object/Map.

You should ideally have a concrete Response model class for each returned type.